# Getting unresolved reference error in line 5

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print change, after 2 sec but I am getting unresolved reference error in line 5. What should I do?

```
import threading
def inchange():
    global change = 0
    threading.Timer(1, inchange).start()
    change = change + 2
    print(change)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    inchange()
```

Comment: In the code you posted `change` has no value, so there's nothing to add 2 to.

Comment: Move `global change` inside of the function.  Plus what @defladamouse said.

Comment: @defladamouse I tried adding but it is not resolved

Comment: well, show what you tried then, you can [edit] your question

Comment: What Python version is that that allows `global change = 0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how you access global change.

Here is the code:

```
import threading

change = 0

def inchange():
    global change
    threading.Timer(1, inchange).start()
    change = change + 2
    print(change)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    inchange()
```

Output:

```
2
```